# Random number generator, breaks for small numbers

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
    var randomNumber = function(from,to,dec)
{
    var num = Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from;
    var result = Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,dec))/Math.pow(10,dec);
    return result;
};
```

The goal is to get random numbers within a given range and round the result to a given decimal place. It works fine for ranges like 1-10 or 50-100, but when I try a small number like so:

```
randomNumber(0.01,0.05,5)
```

I get bad results like 0.27335 and 1.04333.

Comment: I think this one `var num = Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from;` should be `var num = Math.random()*(to-from)+from;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a reluctant +1 on your calculation. Should be `to-from` without the +1:

```
var randomNumber = function (from, to, dec) {
    var num = Math.random() * (to - from +1) + from;
    var result = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec);
    return result;
};
```

Your code should be as follows:

```
var randomNumber = function (from, to, dec) {
    var num = Math.random() * (to - from) + from;
    var result = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec);
    return result;
};
```

Actually, it can be further shortened by omitting the `result` variable as follows:

```
var randomNumber = function (from, to, dec) {
    var num = Math.random() * (to - from) + from; //Generate a random float
    return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec); //Round it to <dec> digits. Return.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   var randomNumber = function(from,to,dec)
{
    var num = Math.random()*(to-from)+from;
    var result = Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,dec))/Math.pow(10,dec);
    return result;
}
```